# fetch value from table and update second table in same controller in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have two table named as 'travel_request' and 'status'.I have status value.based on that value I want to fetched the status table 'id' and want to update the "travel_request" table status_id in same controller.If I have the status value 'waiting' I want to fet the the id=1 and from status table and need to insert it in travel_request table

status table-id,status
travel_request-id,status_id

```
public function statusUpdate(Request $request)
{
  $request_data = $request->all();
   $id = $request_data['id'];   
   $status=$request_data['status'];  //waiting(1),approved(2), 
  DB::table('travel_request')
        ->where('id',$id )
        ->update(['status_id' => $status]); 
  return response()->json();        
}
```

Comment: What's your `status` table structure i.e. columns ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you mean like this:

```
public function statusUpdate(Request $request)
{
  $request_data = $request->all();
   $id = $request_data['id'];   
   $status=$request_data['status'];  //waiting(1),approved(2), 
  DB::table('travel_request')
        ->where('id',$id )
        ->update(['status_id' => DB::table('status')->where('COLUMN_NAME', $status)->first()->id]); 
  return response()->json();        
}
```

Comment: DB::table('travel_request')
            ->where('id',$id )
            ->update(['status_id' => DB::table('status')->where('status', $status)->first()->id]);   I doesn't return anything

Answer (score 1):

Using Eloquent:

```
public function statusUpdate(Request $request)
{
    $status_id = Status::where('status', $request->status)->first()->id;
    TravelRequest::where('id', $request->id)->update(compact('status_id'));
    return response()->json();        
}
```

Another way to do that is to keep statuses in config file, for example:

```
status => [
    'waiting' => 1,
    'approved' => 2,
],
```

Then code would look like this:

```
public function statusUpdate(Request $request)
{
    TravelRequest::where('id', $request->id)
        ->update(['status_id' => config('conf.status')[$request->status]]);

    return response()->json();        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function statusUpdate(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->id;                        //get the id
    $request['status_id'] = $request->status;  //get the status value on status_id
    DB::table('travel_request')
        ->where('id',$id )
        ->update(only(['status_id']));         //update only status_id field
    return response()->json();        
}
```